# How to output specific php depending on value of content type radio

Tags: theming

In my 'Basic page' content type I've added a yes/no radio field. Currently that is outputting as the value chosen. If yes is chosen I want to output a specific button, if no was chosen I don't want to output anything. How do I go about overriding the basic page template to achieve this?

--EDIT--
I don't want the radio option showing for the site visitor, only for the content editor. I want either the button or nothing showing to the site visitor.

Comment: I have never used it, but I guess you could give this one a try: http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

Comment: Conditional field is for fields in node editing, not in display. Though, using something like "if second field is empty", you could achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using @Neograph734's advice I did use conditional fields.
Within the content type structure I added a field a link field(the button I wanted to conditionally show). Then used the conditional field to show this link when needed.